# Docker container doesn't work properly on Azure WebApps for Linux, however it works on locally.

Tags: linux, azure, docker, web-applications

I have a problem of Azure Web apps (Linux preview) for docker.

I wrote a proxy server by go lang and pack it via Dockerfile. this problem is simply convert jpeg into png format. It works fine locally.

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "github.com/labstack/echo"
    "io"
    "image"
    "image/jpeg"
    "image/png"
    "log"
)

func main() {
e := echo.New()
e.GET("/convertedimage", func(c echo.Context) error {
    source := c.QueryParam("url")
    log.Printf(source)
    response, err := http.Get(source)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer response.Body.Close()
    log.Printf(response.Header.Get("Content-type"));

    if response.Header.Get("Content-type") == "image/jpeg" {
        jpegImage := ImageRead(response.Body)

        pr, pw := io.Pipe()
        go func() {
            err = png.Encode(pw, jpegImage)
            pw.Close()
        }()
        return c.Stream(http.StatusOK, "image/png", pr)
    } else {
        return c.Stream(http.StatusOK, "image/png", response.Body)
    }
})
e.Logger.Fatal(e.Start(":80"))
}

func ImageRead(inputImage io.ReadCloser) (image image.Image) {
    img, err := jpeg.Decode(inputImage)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    inputImage.Close()
    return img
}
```

Also I pack it via Docker file like this.

```
FROM golang:1.7.5

ADD server.go .
RUN go get -u github.com/labstack/echo
RUN go build server.go

ENTRYPOINT ./server

EXPOSE 80
```

However, when I deploy it on Azure web apps (linux preview), it doesn't work.

```
$ go build server.go
$ docker build . -t tsuyoshiushio/imageconvertproxy
$ docker push tsuyoshiushio/imageconvertproxy
$ docker run -p 8093:80 tsuyoshiushio/imageconvertproxy
```

It works fine to call via browser like this.

```
http://localhost:8093/convertedimage?url=https%3A%2F%2Fc.s-microsoft.com%2Fja-jp%2FCMSImages%2Fspk-ushio.jpg%3Fversion%3Df6328834-736f-4b59-2f85-7b198346ef4d
-> (I can see a png image on my browser.)
```

Howerver, if I deploy it on an Azure web Apps, it doesn't work at all.

```
https://imageproxy.azurewebsites.net/convertedimage?url=https%3A%2F%2Fc.s-microsoft.com%2Fja-jp%2FCMSImages%2Fspk-ushio.jpg%3Fversion%3Df6328834-736f-4b59-2f85-7b198346ef4d
-> {"message":"Not Found"}
```

It is the same behavior as the worng url. But docker container itself is successfully working.

Now we cant' docker exec or docker logs on the container of Web Apps, I have no idea to solve this problem. Do you have any ideas for solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your container expose port 8093,but by default App Service uses port 80. Luckily this setting is configurable.

Go to Application Settings and add a setting named PORT and set it to 8093. More information please refer to this [link](http://anthonychu.ca/post/jekyll-azure-app-service-linux/).

Update:

I notice that you access your web by using https, the port is 443, not 80. Try to use `http` and test again.

Comment: Thanks! I expose 80 on the App Service. Not 8093. This is not the problem of the firewall of App Service. Because I've got message '{"message":"Not Found"}' This json returned from go server inside my container. 
This json is the same symptom when I do like this.
true: http://localhost:8093/convertedimage?url=.... false: http://localhost:8093/wrongone?url=

Comment: Could you access your web by using `http://localhost/convertedimage?url=https%3A%2F%2Fc.s-microsoft.com%2Fja-jp%2FCMSImages%2Fspk-ushio.jpg%3Fversion%3Df6328834-736f-4b59-2f85-7b198346ef4d` ?

Comment: Hi, do you try `http` not `https`?

Comment: Hi,  I notice that you access your web by using `https`, the port is 443, not 80. If possible, I suggest you could try to use `http` test again.

Comment: Great! This is it! Thanks. I don't know why I used https. Ops!

Comment: Although, I try 'https' now it works. very weird... 'http' also works. I don't know why it work. yesterday it didn't and I don't change anything. However, it's fine for me. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, do you add port 443. By default, it only expose port 80.

Comment: Thanks again. :) It make me clarify the App Services behavior.

Comment: This link is really useful! Thanks, Walter! I accepted it.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the official FAQ from MS (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/app-service-linux-faq) makes one think that you only need to set WEBSITES_PORT to the port that your container exposes, and that the PORT app setting is to be depricated, but it is still very much in use, so to be sure, set both WEBSITES_PORT and PORT to the port that your container exposes.
Note that regardless of the port your container exposes, you access your web app on port 80 for HTTP and 443 for HTTPS.